# Multiple Financial Types on one payment form?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, price-sets, financial-types

Is there a way to specify multiple financial types on one contribution or registration form? For example, what would be the best way to set up a page that allowed a gala ticket purchase and also allowed sponsorship levels (if desired)? We can set up multiple price sets on a contribution form to allow the separate selection of a ticket and a sponsorship level, but they would all be the same financial type.

In this case, I suppose the best case would be to set up an event for the gala, allow registration including a few custom price sets, but to be able to break those extra (optional) donation/sponsorship items out as the 'Donation' (or 'Sponsorship') financial type rather than 'Event fee'.

Is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use price sets then each field, or each option on multiple option fields, can have its own financial type. Currently, event price sets support contributions (FWIW, membership price sets also support contributions, but it's not yet possible to have memberships and event tickets in the same price set).

The trouble you are having is the simplified price sets on the Fees tab all use the same financial type. Note that just above that simplified interface there is a link you can use to convert your existing options into a complex price set: 'Click *here* if you want to configure the Regular Fees below as part of a Price Set, with the added flexibility and complexity that entails.'

Comment: Wow, somehow I saw the default financial type on the price set but looked right past the financial type on the individual fields. Thanks!